# How to build a container from multiple Maven projects

Tags: maven, ibm-cloud

I am creating a microservice to deploy on the cloud using Docker and Kubernetes. This requires code from multiple Maven Java projects that are not on any public repository. For example, the `microservice` project has a dependency on a `analytics` project which has a dependency on a `model` project. There is no inheritance between the POMs of these projects. Locally, the `microservice` Maven project builds successfully using the artefacts already in the local Maven repository. However, when I try to build a container from the `microservice` project, it fails because Maven in the docker build cannot find the `analytics` and `model` jars in the container's Maven repository.

What are my best options for making the `model` and `analytics` projects available to the image build so that I can build the docker image?

Comment: There are in general two solutions. The first one is using a repository to store those artifacts inside your corporate environment the second one would be to make a single multi module build of them ?

Comment: I meant to use a repository manager ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the build within docker can't see the artifacts that are only installed in your local maven. If they logically fit together (i.e. they're only ever used together) then it would make sense to combine them into a single multi-module Maven build with a single parent pom. It sounds like this could be your situation.

Otherwise your best options are:

1 Host the artifacts that docker currently can't see in a public repo. If you have a nexus you can use you could install them there.

2 Build your jar outside docker and copy the artifact in. This means a change to your dockerfile and effectively a Maven pre-docker step in your build.

3 A variation on 2 but combine the Maven and docker steps with a Maven plugin. For example you could use the Spotify docker Maven plugin.